# Clarification on a notation in ODE: $u^{(iv)} = 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, notation

I'm asked to find to fundamental solution of the following ODE problem:

$$u^{(iv)} = 0$$

However, I have no clue what $u^{(iv)}$ means, can someone explain this notation to me? Thanks in advance!

Comment: One possibility is it's the 4th derivative of $u$.  Some people think of $u'$, $u''$, $u'''$ as having Roman numerals I, II, III in the exponent, in which case IV would naturally be the 4th derivative.  But without more context it's hard to know for sure.

Comment: Aha, that makes a lot of sense! If that's the case, this is a really confusing notation. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The comment by Nate Eldredge, although stated in a tentative form, is the only plausible interpretation of this notation.

> One possibility is it's the 4th derivative of $u$.  Some people think of $u'$, $u''$, $u'''$ as having Roman numerals I, II, III in the exponent, in which case IV would naturally be the 4th derivative.  But without more context it's hard to know for sure. -- [Nate Eldredge](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1538068/clarification-on-a-notation-in-ode-uiv-0#comment3131996_1538068)